# Implementing Custom functions in Office JS

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have installed Office 365 pro plus in which whether do we need to use custom functions in office JS or still need to join office insider program?

Also shall i use custom functions with task pane by running in development environment or only have to use as hosted as excel add-in?

Guys, any update regarding this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, and how it relates to programming

Comment: Because when our team deployed "developer preview sample" and checked that custom functions not working.

Comment: Hi @Murugaananth, can you provide details of how you're hosting this? What build of Office you are using?   (One thing that may be an issue is if you're using a self-signed certificate.  I'd suggest hosting on http for the developer preview to see if that works)

Answer (score 0):

I have office insider subscription and developed a sample for custom function and published in iis and it is working fine in my excel as I have office insider subscription . But my question is that , other than me , do the other end user who uses the excel without office insider will able to access this custom functions ?? Kindly provide your thought.

Comment: Hi Sorry I missed this. Other users will be able to use your add-ins if they sideload that add-in in an Office Insiders build as well, while the feature is still in preview.

Comment: @Keyur, also users who don't have Insider subscription able to access custom functions with normal Excel(Office profession plus 2016) in desktop version?

Comment: Please see here for versions that support custom function s: https://aka.ms/customfunctions. It works on the Monthly channel and will be available on the next semi annual update rolling out in a couple of months.